# Percentage labels on a stacked column graph

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following calculated field in Tableau :

```
[Nb of articles]/TOTAL(COUNT([Post reach]))
```

However I want my total to be calculated only at a weekly level.

Hope I'm clear.

Thanks !

Comment: Is [Post reach] a date? What is this field?

Comment: I totally forgot I had this question opened. I found the answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [on the community of Tableau users](https://community.tableau.com/thread/152591) :

```
1. Select the measure second time (Row/Column shelf)
2. Click on this second selected measure in the row shelf (or column where its kept)
3. Move to the "Quick Table Calculation" in the drop down menu which appeared
4. Select "Percentage of Total" from the sub menu (This should add a second chart with percentages)
5. Now, drag and drop the measure to Label (second chart would disappear as measure is moved to label mark)
```

Very easy ! :)